# For Continuous RVs $X$ and $Y$ if $Y=$ "the CDF of $X$ evaluated in $X$" why does that mean $Y$ is uniform over (0,1)?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with CDF $F$. Define the random variable $Y=F(X)$, show that $Y$ is uniformly distributed over $(0,1)$.

I have literally no idea why this would even be none the less how to prove it. please help.

Comment: Look carefully at the definition of $Y$. The $X$ inside it is the first random variable.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
prove that $$t\in(0,1)\implies P(Y< t) = t$$

and use the fact that the CDF of $X$ is strictly increasing and continuous.

---

Solution:
under these hypothesis, $F$ is invertible and
$$
P(Y < t) = P(F(X) < t) = P(X < F^{-1}(t)) = F(F^{-1}(t)) =t
$$

Comment: also that the CDF of $X$ is continuous

Comment: @Henry thanks!${}$

Answer (score 0):

For $t\in\left(0,1\right)$ define $z\left(t\right)=\inf\left\{ x\in\mathbb{R}\mid F\left(x\right)\geq t\right\} $.

Then $F^{-1}\left(\left[t,1\right]\right)=\left[z\left(t\right),\infty\right)$
with $P\left(X<z\left(t\right)\right)\leq t\leq P\left(X\leq z\left(t\right)\right)$.

$F\left(X\right)<t\iff X<z\left(t\right)$ so $P\left(F\left(X\right)<t\right)=P\left(X<z\left(t\right)\right)\leq t$

If $F$ is continuous at $z\left(t\right)$ then $P\left(X<z\left(t\right)\right)=P\left(X\leq z\left(t\right)\right)=t$
leading to $P\left(F\left(X\right)<t\right)=t$.

If $F$ is a continuous function then $P\left(F\left(X\right)<t\right)=t$ for each $t\in\left(0,1\right)$.